# How do I access multiple records from multiple database tables?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I want to retrieve the Username records from tblUser and the Link records from tblResults.

```
import sqlite3

connUsers = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
users = connUsers.cursor()

def create_user_tbl():
      try:
        users.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE tblUser (
          UserID        INTEGER, 
          Username      TEXT, 
          Password      TEXT, 
    
          PRIMARY KEY   (UserID) )""")
        
        tblUser = [
          (1, 'Argon456', 'Fir3Tru0k'), (2, 'Max9', 'Thrsgdp0fnse'), (3, 'Steven', '1234')] 
        users.executemany("INSERT INTO tblUser VALUES (?, ?, ?)", tblUser); print("Database created")
      except: print("Database table already exists")
    
def create_results_tbl():
      try:
        users.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE tblResults (
          ResultsID   INTEGER, 
          Title       TEXT, 
          Location    TEXT,
          Link        TEXT,
          
          PRIMARY KEY (ResultsID) )""")
        
        tblResults = [
          (1, 'Business', 'Ayelsbury', 'www.link.com'), (2, 'Apprenticeship', 'Ealing', 'https://ealingpress.co.uk')]
        users.executemany("INSERT INTO tblResults VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", tblResults); print("Database created")
      except: print("Database table already exists")

for row in users.execute("SELECT A.Username, B.Link FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.UserID = B.ResultsID;"):
  print(row)
users.commit()
users.close()
```

I believe my SELECT statement is correct but I cannot test it as I do not know how to execute this command. To access multiple records from different tables, do I need to create multiple connections to each .db file? If not, would I execute the command through the first table in the SELECT statement?

Comment: What does UserID have to do with ResultsID? How are these columns related?

Comment: Multiple databases or multiple tables?

Comment: `tblResults` should have a foreign key to `tblUser`.

Comment: @Barmar why and what difference does it make if the records can be retrieved without?

Comment: Without a foreign key, how do you know which results are for which user?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()


def create_user_tbl():
    connection.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE tblUser (
          UserID        INTEGER, 
          Username      TEXT, 
          Password      TEXT, 

          PRIMARY KEY   (UserID) )""")
    print("Database created")

def populate_user():
        users = [
            (1, 'Argon456', 'Fir3Tru0k'),
            (2, 'Max9', 'Thrsgdp0fnse'),
            (3, 'Steven', '1234')
        ]

        connection.executemany("INSERT INTO tblUser VALUES (?, ?, ?)", users)

def create_results_tbl():
    connection.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE tblResults (
          ResultsID   INTEGER, 
          Title       TEXT, 
          Location    TEXT,
          Link        TEXT,

          PRIMARY KEY (ResultsID) )""")

def populate_results():
    results = [
        (1, 'Business', 'Ayelsbury', 'www.link.com'),
        (2, 'Apprenticeship', 'Ealing', 'https://ealingpress.co.uk')
    ]
    connection.executemany("INSERT INTO tblResults VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", results);


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create_user_tbl()
    # create_results_tbl()
    # populate_user()
    # populate_results()
    # connection.commit()

    for row in connection.execute("SELECT tblUser.Username, tblResults.Link FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblResults ON tblUser.UserID = tblResults.ResultsID;"):
        print(row)
```

prints

```
('Argon456', 'www.link.com')
('Max9', 'https://ealingpress.co.uk')
```

Comment: You're using the primary key of `tblResults` as the foreign key to `tblUsers`. That makes no sense. Why would there be a 1-to-1 relation like this?

Comment: I know. but ask the Flamenco33 why he wants to join that way... :)